# Converting Informix schema to PostgreSQL schema

Tags: postgresql, schema, informix

How can I convert INFORMIX-SQL Version 11.50.FC3  schema to PostgreSQL 9.2 schema?

Comment: Dump the schema to a text file, and use a text editor? See if there's anything useful here: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

I did some conversions as Craig said:

1. `dbexport` of Informix database
2. some search & replace in schema text file (I use Python for such things).
3. on PostgreSQL server: `psql -f [schema_file] new_database`
4. analyze `psql` output and if something is wrong drop new PostgreSQL database, and correct search & replace tools (goto 2)

When you convert all interesting things into PostgreSQL you can compare both schemas using my tools like: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576621-dump-informix-schema-to-text/

Those tools are used mainly to compare Informix vs other Informix or PostgreSQL vs other PostgreSQL database but after some normalizing I believe you can compare PostgreSQL vs Informix.